# Mule print BufferInputStream using payloadAs

Tags: mule

The log message below is aimed at printing out a json error response from my api.

```
<logger message="#[exception.getCauseException()?.getMuleMessage()?.getPayload()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

The result of this log message is

> org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@486bf09a

I have a requirement to pass the json response. How can I turn the above log line into something like this where it will pass the stream rather than just printing BufferInputStream.toString()...

```
<logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

I tried the following below that does not work.

```
<logger message="#[exception.getCauseException()?.getMuleMessage().payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

By the way logging a stream is not the real purpose as to why I want to parse the stream. I know that is an expensive operation. I really need to pass the stream to get some meaningful information from the response.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, you are going to have to convert the output into a string to access it. Then you will have to manipulate the output using string methods to get the desired information.

Comment: I ended up doing that in a Groovy script and it worked.

Comment: Did you try the `ObjectToString` Transformer ?